# HangFire running each job separately

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, backgroundworker, hangfire

I am using HangFire to run the job. I have a method that retrieve data from more than 50 sql servers.
I want to use HangFire to run each location separately by LocationID, and if 1 location fails I want that job get running again for that location after x minutes.
Also I want to see the log of the job on the HangFire Dashboard.

My job method :

```
    public void SyncCompInfo()
    {
        List<Location> locations;
        using (var db = new CompInfoDemoEntities())
        {
            locations = db.Locations.Where(x => x.IsActive).ToList();
        }
        foreach (var location in locations)
        {
            try
            {
                using (var _db = new CompInfoDemoEntities())
                {

                    _log.Info("Getting CompoInfo data from location: " + location.StoreName);
                    _syncLogService.Add("Getting CompoInfo data from location: " + location.StoreName);
                    var responses = new List<CompInfoResponse>();
                    var compInfos = _db.IMS_CompInfo.Where(x => x.LocationId == location.Id).ToList();
                    using (var cnn = new SqlConnection(location.ConnectionString))
                    {
                        var sql = "select * from IMS_CompInfo;";
                        var sqlCmd = new SqlCommand(sql, cnn);
                        cnn.Open();
                        using (SqlDataReader rdr = sqlCmd.ExecuteReader())
                        {
                            while (rdr.Read())
                            {
                                var item = new CompInfoResponse();
                                item.Id = int.Parse(rdr["Id"].ToString());
                                item.ClientID = rdr["ClientID"].ToString();
                                item.LicenceID = rdr["LicenceID"].ToString();
                                item.POSCode = rdr["POSCode"].ToString();
                                item.logiPOS_Version = rdr["logiPOS_Version"].ToString();
                                if (rdr["LastLoginDate"] != null)
                                {
                                    item.LastLoginDate = DateTime.Parse(rdr["LastLoginDate"].ToString());
                                }

                                item.ComputerName = rdr["ComputerName"].ToString();
                                if (rdr["BootTime"] != null)
                                {
                                    item.BootTime = DateTime.Parse(rdr["BootTime"].ToString());
                                }

                                item.Domain = rdr["Domain"].ToString();
                                item.Manufacturer = rdr["Manufacturer"].ToString();
                                item.Model = rdr["Model"].ToString();
                                item.Memory = rdr["Memory"].ToString();
                                item.OS = rdr["OS"].ToString();
                                item.Build = rdr["Build"].ToString();
                                item.CPU = rdr["CPU"].ToString();
                                item.ProcArchitecture = rdr["ProcArchitecture"].ToString();
                                item.IP1 = rdr["IP1"].ToString();
                                item.MAC1 = rdr["MAC1"].ToString();
                                if (rdr["LastModifiedDate"] != null)
                                {
                                    item.LastModifiedDate = DateTime.Parse(rdr["LastModifiedDate"].ToString());
                                }

                                if (rdr["Tag"] != null)
                                {
                                    item.Tag = int.Parse(rdr["Tag"].ToString());
                                }

                                item.Application = rdr["Application"].ToString();
                                responses.Add(item);
                            }
                        }
                    }
```

Comment: Submit each server as a separate job.  Hangfire retry policy will handle any jobs that fail.

Comment: thanx for your reply @ScottMildenberger, can you show me an example how i can do it?

Comment: how are you running the above code in Hangfire?

Comment: @ScottMildenberger i call the method SyncCompInfo.  from the startup hangfire conifguration         public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
        {
            ConfigureAuth(app);
            var locationService = new LocationService();
            GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.UseSqlServerStorage("DefaultConnection");
            app.UseHangfireDashboard();
            RecurringJob.AddOrUpdate(() => locationService.SyncCompInfo(), Cron.Hourly);
            app.UseHangfireServer();     
        }

Comment: @ScottMildenberger my project is on ASP.net MVC

Comment: I don't have time right now to do a complete example.  Research BackgroundJob.Enqueue() method.  In your loop of locations extract code for a single location to another method and then Enqueue that method for each location.  We have built an event handling process on top of Hangfire running as service so can't just copy our code.  Depending on what you are doing with the results you may need another job to combine everything when they are all done.

Answer (score 1):

What you seem to need is something like this, with a method you call upon startup, which loops other the locations and enqueues a job for each location.
I over simplified the thing (for example making the methods static),
but I guess most of the idea is there.

Have a look at [Hangfire recurring tasks](https://docs.hangfire.io/en/latest/background-methods/performing-recurrent-tasks.html) I guess it may be better suited to your needs than tasks fired upon application startups.

```
public void CalledUponStartup()
{
    List<Location> locations;
    using (var db = new CompInfoDemoEntities())
    {
        locations = db.Locations.Where(x => x.IsActive).ToList();
    }
    foreach (var location in locations)
    {
      BackgroundJob.Enqueue(() => SyncCompInfo(location.Id));
    }       
}

public static void SyncCompInfo(int locationId)
{
        try
        {
            using (var _db = new CompInfoDemoEntities())
            {
                 var location = db.Locations.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id == locationId);

                _log.Info("Getting CompoInfo data from location: " + location.StoreName);
                _syncLogService.Add("Getting CompoInfo data from location: " + location.StoreName);
                var responses = new List<CompInfoResponse>();
                var compInfos = _db.IMS_CompInfo.Where(x => x.LocationId == location.Id).ToList();
                using (var cnn = new SqlConnection(location.ConnectionString))
                {
                    var sql = "select * from IMS_CompInfo;";
                    var sqlCmd = new SqlCommand(sql, cnn);
                    cnn.Open();
                    using (SqlDataReader rdr = sqlCmd.ExecuteReader())
                    {
                        while (rdr.Read())
                        {
                            var item = new CompInfoResponse();
                            item.Id = int.Parse(rdr["Id"].ToString());
                            item.ClientID = rdr["ClientID"].ToString();
                            item.LicenceID = rdr["LicenceID"].ToString();
                            item.POSCode = rdr["POSCode"].ToString();
                            item.logiPOS_Version = rdr["logiPOS_Version"].ToString();
                            if (rdr["LastLoginDate"] != null)
                            {
                                item.LastLoginDate = DateTime.Parse(rdr["LastLoginDate"].ToString());
                            }

                            item.ComputerName = rdr["ComputerName"].ToString();
                            if (rdr["BootTime"] != null)
                            {
                                item.BootTime = DateTime.Parse(rdr["BootTime"].ToString());
                            }

                            item.Domain = rdr["Domain"].ToString();
                            item.Manufacturer = rdr["Manufacturer"].ToString();
                            item.Model = rdr["Model"].ToString();
                            item.Memory = rdr["Memory"].ToString();
                            item.OS = rdr["OS"].ToString();
                            item.Build = rdr["Build"].ToString();
                            item.CPU = rdr["CPU"].ToString();
                            item.ProcArchitecture = rdr["ProcArchitecture"].ToString();
                            item.IP1 = rdr["IP1"].ToString();
                            item.MAC1 = rdr["MAC1"].ToString();
                            if (rdr["LastModifiedDate"] != null)
                            {
                                item.LastModifiedDate = DateTime.Parse(rdr["LastModifiedDate"].ToString());
                            }

                            if (rdr["Tag"] != null)
                            {
                                item.Tag = int.Parse(rdr["Tag"].ToString());
                            }

                            item.Application = rdr["Application"].ToString();
                            responses.Add(item);
                        }
                }
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. what about the log on Hangfire DashBoard, I want to see log for each of locations, and if any of Locations Fails I want the job to be executed again for that location.

Comment: That's how it will work. One job per location, so one log per job, and retry policy per job.

Comment: I am trying some test, so i know x locations has problem. but the HangFire log say it's Succeeded, so it doesn't catch any error with the location connection.

Comment: You did not show what is in your catch clause. If you don't rethrow the exceptions, it won't be considered an error by Hangfire

Comment: You need a `throw;` at the end of your catch clause